# Common Template for JPanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel

I want to create a common JPanel template that will be used by all the other panel. The Common JPanel Template would have a common header and footer. Below is the sample code of the common template JPanel.

```
import javax.swing.*;
public abstract class AbstractPanel extends JPanel {
    public AbstractPanel() {
        super();
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        init();
        addHeader();
        addComponentsToScreen();
        addFooter();
    }

    private void addHeader() {
        add(new JLabel("Common Header"));
    }

    private void addFooter() {
        add(new JLabel("Common Footer"));
    }

    protected abstract void init();
    protected abstract void addComponentsToScreen();
}
```

Now I want to create a JPanel using this AbstractPanel with two different layouts based on the input parameter.

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class MyPanel extends AbstractPanel {
    private boolean showDept;
    private JTextField jTextEmp;
    private JTextField jTextName;
    private JTextField jTextDept;
    public MyPanel(boolean showDept) {
        super();
        this.showDept = showDept;
    }

    protected void init() {
        jTextEmp = new JTextField();
        jTextName = new JTextField();
        jTextDept = new JTextField();
    }

    protected void addComponentsToScreen() {
        add(new JLabel("Employee"));
        add(jTextEmp);
        add(new JLabel("Name"));
        add(jTextName);
        if(showDept) {
            add(new JLabel("Dept"));
            add(jTextDept);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.add(new MyPanel(true));
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setSize(200, 500);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The problem with the above code is that the showDept is always false for the method addComponentsToScreen as it is called from the superclass constructor. Is there a better way to do this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Make your super class constructor a parameterised constructor and pass showDept to super class constructor.

Sample Code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
public abstract class AbstractPanel extends JPanel {
 private boolean showDept; // add public getter for it
    public AbstractPanel(boolean showDept) {
        super();
        this.showDept = showDept;
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        init();
        addHeader();
        addComponentsToScreen();
        addFooter();
    }

    private void addHeader() {
        add(new JLabel("Common Header"));
    }

    private void addFooter() {
        add(new JLabel("Common Footer"));
    }

    protected abstract void init();
    protected abstract void addComponentsToScreen();
}
```

MyPanel class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class MyPanel extends AbstractPanel {
    private boolean showDept;
    private JTextField jTextEmp;
    private JTextField jTextName;
    private JTextField jTextDept;
    public MyPanel(boolean showDept) {
        super(showDept);
    }

    protected void init() {
        jTextEmp = new JTextField();
        jTextName = new JTextField();
        jTextDept = new JTextField();
    }

    protected void addComponentsToScreen() {
        add(new JLabel("Employee"));
        add(jTextEmp);
        add(new JLabel("Name"));
        add(jTextName);
        if(getShowDept()) {
            add(new JLabel("Dept"));
            add(jTextDept);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.add(new MyPanel(true));
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setSize(200, 500);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: In the above code, the boolean variable showDept is specific to the MyPanel and should be used in AbstractPanel.

Answer (score 0):

Other way around, make your panels totally independent from the each other. as this application basic you want to keep same header and footer on very view you can use following.

```
    class MyDynamicPanel extends JPanel {
    public MyDynamicPanel() {
        super();
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        addAppHeader();
        addAppFooter();
    }

    private void addAppHeader() {
        add(new JLabel("Common Header"),BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }
    public void addAppCenter(JPanel centerPanel){
        add(centerPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
    private void addAppFooter() {
        add(new JLabel("Common Footer"),BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }
}
```

This use border layout to adjust itself in every size of screen or frame.
Now your custom panel.

```
   public class MyPanel extends MyDynamicPanel {
    private JTextField jTextEmp;
    private JTextField jTextName;
    private JTextField jTextDept;
    private JPanel centerPanel;
    public MyPanel() {
        super();
        init();
        addComponentsToScreen();
    }

    protected void init() {
        centerPanel = new JPanel();
        jTextEmp = new JTextField("",20);
        jTextName = new JTextField("",20);
        jTextDept = new JTextField("",10);
    }

    protected void addComponentsToScreen() {
       centerPanel.add(new JLabel("Name"));
       centerPanel.add(jTextEmp);
       centerPanel.add(new JLabel("Employee"));
       centerPanel.add(jTextName);
       centerPanel.add(new JLabel("dept"));
       centerPanel.add(jTextDept);

       addAppCenter(centerPanel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.add(new MyPanel());
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setSize(200, 500);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

This Panel can have its own layout and components